# Populate id of array in aggregation in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am suffering from a problem, can u please help me to populate the message array ids.

```
await Message.aggregate([
    { $match: { $and: [{ receiver }, { delivered: null }] } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $switch: { branches: [{ case: { $eq: ['$sender', receiver] }, then: '$receiver' }], default: '$sender' } },
            receiver: { $last: '$receiver' },
            message: { $push: '$_id' },
        }
    },
    { $project: {message: 1, } },
    { $sort: { 'sent': -1 } }  ])
```

And the result with above code is

```
{
"status": "success",
"syncat": "2021-10-31T04:13:39.935Z",
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "616b21735498275d803c7b09",
        "message": [
            "617cccf00ba86ff28c543475",
            "617ccd3b5375bafe008cec05",
            
        ]
    }
]}
```

I want to populate every id of the message array from the Message module.
that should look like

```
{
"status": "success",
"syncat": "2021-10-31T04:13:39.935Z",
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "617cccf00ba86ff28c543475",
        "message": [
                    {
                       //Message Data
                    {
                       //Message Data
                    }                
       ]
    }
]}
```

The modules that I made for it is User and Message

Comment: you should have a look at this 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

use `$$ROOT` in `message: { $push: '$$ROOT' }`